# SQL Server Data Tools - Find all external references

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to create a DACPAC for an existing SQL Server database, but I am getting errors because of external references.

I'd like to try to get a full list of ALL the external references in SQL Server along with information about the stored proc/view where they are located.

Is there a query I can run in SQL Server (2017) to return this information?

EDIT: To clarify, I don't want to suppress the errors, I want them to be addressed, but I need the full list before I can proceed.

Comment: What languages do you know? Would you be happy with c# or is it just t-sql?

Comment: Have you tried doing a find in the source for anything with *.dbo.* or *.[dbo].*?  That might get you to a decent starting point of affected objects and things to look at.  Be sure to limit to *.sql files.

Comment: @EdElliott, I'd prefer SQL, but C# is fine if that's not an option.